# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@MedTypeID' to data type int

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

What I am trying to do is auto fill some labels that have been placed on the form with some sql data when a selection is made as seen here.

```
protected void ddlMedication_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strMedTypeID = lblMedType.Text;
    string strMedName = ddlMedication.SelectedValue;
    using (SqlConnection conn1 = new
    SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AwesomeConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT DISTINCT [num], [MedType_ID], [MedName], [MedMin], [MedMax], [ChargingNumber] 
                                               FROM [pharm_medications] WHERE [MedType_ID] = '@MedTypeID' AND [MedName] = '@MedName'", conn1);

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedTypeID",strMedTypeID);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedName",strMedName);
            conn1.Open();
            var reader3 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            reader3.Read();
            int myNum = reader3.GetInt32(0);
            string strMedTypeID = reader3.GetString(1);
            string strMyMedName = reader3.GetString(2);
            string strMedMin = reader3.GetString(3);
            string strMedMax = reader3.GetString(4);
            string strChargingNumber = reader3.GetString(5);
            reader3.Close();
            lblAutoMin.Text = strMedMin;
            lblAutoMax.Text = strMedMax;
            lblAutoChargeNum.Text = strChargingNumber;
        }

}
```

When I set the control's `AutoPostBack` to `true` I get this as an error: ***Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@MedTypeID' to data type int***. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Remove single quotes around your parameters in `WHERE` clause

This:

```
WHERE [MedType_ID] = '@MedTypeID' AND [MedName] = '@MedName'
```

Should be:

```
WHERE [MedType_ID] = @MedTypeID AND [MedName] = @MedName
```

So your query would be:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT DISTINCT [num], [MedType_ID], [MedName],
                     [MedMin], [MedMax], [ChargingNumber] FROM [pharm_medications] 
                     WHERE [MedType_ID] = @MedTypeID AND [MedName] = @MedName", conn1);
```

Consider enclosing your command object in [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) statement as well.

Comment: I thought it was enclosed....the `using`s `}` does not end until after all of the `GetString`s

Comment: @Skullomania, only your connection is enclosed in `using` statement.